# Refresh div and FadeIn new results

Tags: jquery

This code refreshes a table contained in a div every 10 seconds:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $( '#allCases' ).fadeOut(500).load(window.location.href + ' #allCases' ).fadeIn(2000);
}, 10000);
```

The refresh works fine, and the fade works fine, but they are out of sync. The fade happens, and then the new data flickers in 2 seconds later. I want the new data to be fading in.

Comment: Hide the loaded data and then put the fadeIn in load's callback

Comment: if you want a cross fade effect you'll have to do something along these lines https://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a time interval then you have to remove that. Then only it will works perfect otherwise the book will tuning infinitely .. what you have to do is. U need to assign the time interval function to a variable then check it before the the time interval of there or not. If there then remove it ..

Eg:
    If(id) clearTimeout(id); 
    var id = setInterval(function(){
       $( '#allCases' ).load(window.location.href + ' #allCases' 
    ).fadeIn(2000);
    }, 10000);

Answer (score 0):

Hide the loaded data in a absolute positioned element with a higher `z-index` than the content. Crossfade this new element `#newCases` with the content `#allCases` and swap their id attributes to complete the cycle.

Quick example:

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#allCases').attr('id', 'oldCases');
    $('#newCases').load(window.location.href + ' #allCases', function(){
      $(this).hide().fadeIn(800, function() {
        $('#allCases').unwrap();
        $('#oldCases').attr('id', 'newCases').empty();
      });
    });
  }, 10000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#oldCases {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#allCases {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#newCases {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Container for positioning -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- Normal content -->
  <div id="allCases">The content goes here</div>

  <!-- New content is loaded in here -->
  <div id="newCases"></div>

</div>
```

> **Note:** In the snippet result above, `.load()` will return nothing because `window.location.href + ' #allCases'` is specific to your project.

Comment: This almost seems to work perfectly! The only problem is, every 10 seconds, the updated table just fades in and out for a brief moment. Then it is gone, and comes back in 10 seconds for another brief moment, etc.

How can I modify the code to keep the newCases shown after they fade in? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @jm92 I've updated the snippet to account for the disappearing content by adding a temporary third id. Now your div's will no longer be interfering with each other.